# Stop midi notes buffering in c#

Tags: c#, midi

I have created a program in C# for my children to test them on reading music.  It displays random notes at set intervals (determined by a timer) and then checks the currently displayed note against input from the keyboard to see if they got it right.  It is working well, apart from the fact that if two notes are accidentally pressed at once, the second of them is taken to be the intended answer for the subsequent note, which hasn't even been displayed yet!  I assume that the notes that are played on the musical keyboard are stored in a buffer and then used when next needed.  I would like to be able to "wipe the slate clean" when a new note is displayed on the screen, so that any previous input is disregarded.  I'd be grateful for any thoughts as to how I can do this please.

Some of the code is below:

```
using System;
using Midi;
using System.Media;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create persistent delegates which we can add and remove to events.
            noteOnHandler = new InputDevice.NoteOnHandler(this.NoteOn);
            noteOffHandler = new InputDevice.NoteOffHandler(this.NoteOff);
            InputDevice preferredInputDevice = InputDevice.InstalledDevices[0];
            UseInputDevice(InputDevice.InstalledDevices[0]);
        }

        private void UseInputDevice(InputDevice newInputDevice)
        {
            if (newInputDevice == inputDevice)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (inputDevice != null)
            {
                if (inputDevice.IsOpen)
                {
                    if (inputDevice.IsReceiving)
                    {
                        inputDevice.StopReceiving();
                    }
                    inputDevice.Close();
                }
                inputDevice.NoteOn -= noteOnHandler;
                inputDevice.NoteOff -= noteOffHandler;
            }
            inputDevice = newInputDevice;
            inputDevice.NoteOn += noteOnHandler;
            inputDevice.NoteOff += noteOffHandler;
            inputDevice.Open();
            inputDevice.StartReceiving(null);
        }

        // Method called when the input device receives a NoteOn message.  Updates
        // the input status label.  Respects GUI thread affinity by invoking to the
        // GUI thread if necessary.
        public void NoteOn(NoteOnMessage msg)
        {
            if (button1.Text == "STOP")
            {
                if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    BeginInvoke(noteOnHandler, msg);
                    return;
                }
                if (string.Equals(String.Format("{0}", msg.Pitch), notename)) { currentscore++; correct[numberofnotes] = true; using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("chime_up.wav")) { player.PlaySync(); } }
                else { using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("klaxon_ahooga.wav")) { player.PlaySync(); } correct[numberofnotes] = false; }
                outof++;
                score.Text = String.Format("{0}", currentscore);
                notesshown.Text = String.Format("{0}", outof);
                numberofticks = 0;
                if (outof < 20) { generate_note(); }
                Redrawit();
                Invalidate();
                if (outof == 20) { reset_screen(); }
            }
        }

        // Method called when the input device receives a NoteOff message.  Updates
        // the input status label.  Respects GUI thread affinity by invoking to the
        // GUI thread if necessary.
        public void NoteOff(NoteOffMessage msg)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                BeginInvoke(noteOffHandler, msg);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Persistent delegate objects for the note handlers.
        private InputDevice.NoteOnHandler noteOnHandler;
        private InputDevice.NoteOffHandler noteOffHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have a short delay (maybe 0.5s) after displaying the note during which you do not process any NoteOn events. Once you display the note, maybe set a flag to simply exit the event, use a timer to clear the flag after the required duration. That would allow any buffered notes to be ignored rather than used as the next answer.

Comment: Your `NoteOn` handler is not called again unless the previous one has finished executing. Play the sound asynchronously, and delay the further  processing with a timer, and ignore all other messages that arrive before that.

Comment: What I'd like to do ideally is to clear anything in the "buffer" when a new note is displayed, but I'm not sure how to do that.....